# Que arquitectura de software usar?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, angular, api, ingenieria-del-software

les comento tengo una aplicacion web hecha en angular la cual llama a una api en java que a su vez con hibernate consulta a base de datos.
La cuestion es: La web en angular iria dentro del hosting pero y la api y la bd?
Las opciones que habia contemplado eran:
-Api y base de datos tambien en el hosting
-Api en hosting y bd en un cloud
-Api y bd en un cloud que por lo visto google tiene esa disponibilidad
Por ultimo probe a por la base de datos en google cloud y funciona pero un poco lento. No se si alguno sabe el porque (igual por la prueba gratuita).
Muchas gracias

Comment: El.titulo no hace referencia directa al prpblema considera mejorarlo

Comment: Primero habría que saber más datos servicios esperas que tenga el alojamiento, base datos a utilizas, si esperas que la base de datos sean administradas por el proveedor o la administraras tú mismo, si será un proyecto productivo o solo un proyecto de prueba y si esperas todo eso en un plan gratuito o pagado, lo digo por tu comentario ` por la prueba gratuita` que presupuesto esperarías tener, y hasta donde esperas escalar la aplicación.